# How to scroll down to particular element in appium using C#

Tags: c#, automation, appium

Can anyone who has experience scrolling a mobile app using C# and Appium help me scroll down to a particular element?

Comment: I have tried it with c# but have done it using java. If you want java code, i can provide you.

Comment: Thanks, I can able to scroll down to the element by using java but not able to  by using c#